# Symfony 1.4 flash messages are lost

Tags: symfony-1.4

In my action:

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash ('error', 'Something went wrong!');
$this->redirect (sfConfig::get('app_default_module'));
```

and in my view:

```
echo $sf_user->getFlash('error');
```

shows nothing. I know its not too much, but what can I do?

Comment: if I do a "var_dump ($_SESSION);" before and after putting the variable, its the same!

Comment: when I do a "forward()" it works OK

Answer (score 0):

If you all want to cry and laugh at the same time: I overridden the "myUser::shutdown()" method, and nobody told to call its parent...